# Iterate different typed Sets into a User defined type List

Tags: java, list, generics, set

I have different typed `Sets` like below :

```
        Set<String> imgs = new LinkedHashSet<String>(this.getImages());

        Set<String> proNames = new LinkedHashSet<String>(this.getProductNames());

        Set<Integer> proQty = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(this.getQty());

        Set<Double> proPrice = new LinkedHashSet<Double>(this.getPrices());
```

And I need to insert all the data in above sets to one user defined typed `ArrayList` like below:

```
List<MyProduct> pList = new ArrayList<MyProduct>();
        for (Iterator<Double> iterator = proPrice.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Double next = iterator.next();
            pList.add(new MyProduct(?, ?, ?, next));
        }
```

**Consider the sizes of all the Sets are same.**(All 4 sets consist same amount of data)

`MyProduct` class:

```
public class MyProduct {

    private String image;
    private String proName;
    private int qty;
    private double price;


    public MyProduct(String image, String proName, int qty, double price) {
        this.image = image;
        this.proName = proName;
        this.qty = qty;
        this.price = price;
    }
      //getters and setters
       ...
```

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE :**
Will assume that I have 4 `ArrayLists` instead of `Sets` :

```
public ArrayList<String> proNames = new ArrayList();
public ArrayList<Double> proPrice = new ArrayList();
public ArrayList<Integer> proQty = new ArrayList();
public ArrayList<String> imgs = new ArrayList<String>();
```

But in these lists duplicates may include.Which means `proNames`has got two products *Apple* and *Banana*.But in `proPrice` we have got prices for both *Apple* and *Banana* but with duplicates.

> (Ex: Lets assume *Apple--> $1* and *Banana--> $2*. In
>   `proPrice`-->[1,2,2] price for banana two times.).

So in this situation  how can I put these data in my `List<MyProduct>` ??

Comment: Why do you put the data into sets in the first place? You cannot access an element by index via a set, so a regular loop is out of the question. You may want to use lists, unless you are justifiably attempting to prevent duplicates. You could then use an indexed loop to access each element from the lists.

Comment: Yes.I have some duplicate elements . Thats why using Sets instead of Lists.

Comment: Sets are unordered, so if your four collections are supposed to be parallel, you need to use lists or ordered sets (e.g. `LinkedHashSet`)

Comment: Are all of the duplicates the same?  This seems a terrible idea.  Lists are really the way to go here, and then deal with any duplicate resolution after combining them into MyProducts.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I have to remove duplicates before combine them into `myProducts`.

Comment: @johndoe, what duplicates?  Duplicate images?  Duplicate prices?  If you have any of those it will destroy the ordering and there will be no way to sort out which is which again.  What you're asking for makes no sense.

Comment: `list.addAll(imgs);` will helpful ??

Comment: @john doe: I've updated my answer now that you've updated to say that you're holding your components in lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constructing an `List` of `MyProduct`s by combining associated pieces of the components in various component sets which contain no information about which elements are related is impossible. How do you know which components go with which others?

The ideal solution is to not put the components (`image`, `proName`, `qty` and `price`) into `Set`s at all, so that you can avoid destroying the relationships among them. This of course begs the question of how you know the relationships among them in the first place. Assuming you have such a mechanism (if you don't then this will be impossible to solve), I'll abstract it away by assuming you can write functions like `getImage(enumerator)` where `enumerator` is something like an index into a bunch of lists or a key into a bunch of `Map`s. I'll further assume you can enumerate all the possible identifiers in a `Collection` `enumerators`. Finally, in case you have duplicates, I'll assume you can identify whether something is a duplicate or not by using one of the fields of the product- probably the `proName`. With all these assumptions in place, you can construct a unique `Set` of `MyProduct`s as follows:

```
Map<String,MyProduct> uniqueProducts = new HashMap<>();
for(TypeOfEnumerator enumerator : enumerators){

    if(!uniqueProducts.contains(getProName(enumerator))){
        //You've stated a requirement that you avoid duplication
        //before you even create a duplicate MyProduct. This if
        //before the construction meets that requirement.
        uniqueProducts.put(getProName(enumerator),
            new MyProduct(getImg(enumerator),getProName(enumerator),getQty(enumerator),getPrice(enumerator)));
    }
}
```

And then, if you want the final result in a `Set` rather than a `Map`:

```
Set<MyProduct> products = new HashSet<MyProduct>(uniqueProducts.values());
```

---

**Note:** Just to be abundantly clear, you won't be able to create the methods like `getImage(enumerator)` so long as the components are in `Sets`. My solution assumes that you leave the `image`s, `qty`s and so on in whatever form they were *before you put them in sets to remove the duplicates*. It manages avoiding the duplication using the `Map` and the `contains` check.

---

**Update**: You have edited your question to say that you are now holding your component pieces in `List`s rather than `Set`s. In that case, `TypeOfEnumerator` is `int`, we can rename `enumerator` to the standard `i`, and the methods `getImage(enumerator)` become `imgs.get(i)`. This makes the code above into:

```
Map<String,MyProduct> uniqueProducts = new HashMap<>();
for(int i=0; i<proNames.size(); i++){

    if(!uniqueProducts.contains(proNames.get(i))){
        //You've stated a requirement that you avoid duplication
        //before you even create a duplicate MyProduct. This if
        //before the construction meets that requirement.
        uniqueProducts.put(proNames.get(i),
            new MyProduct(imgs.get(i),proNames.get(i),proQty.get(i),proPrice.get(i)));
    }
}

Set<MyProduct> products = new HashSet<MyProduct>(uniqueProducts.values());
```

Answer (score 0):

**I don't know why you separate them in the first place ^_^**

But anyway as you say they are all the same length then just one for statement should be enough.

```
List<MyProduct> pList = new List<MyProduct>();
for(int i = 0; i < imgs.Count; i++)
{
    pList.Add(new new MyProduct(imgs[i],proNames[i], proQty[i], proPrice[i]))
}
```

---

***Update*** : Sorry I wrote the example in c# didn't noticed that you want the Java one but I guess it's clear

Comment: What is `Count` here . And `imgs,proNames,proQty,proPrice` are Sets here.

Comment: It's the `yourSet.size()` in Java